# Contact form with AJAX ( without pageload )

Tags: php, ajax

I am new with AJAX, I have to make a modal contact form that pops up. I have everything the html the css the validation etc. Only the AJAX not, I don't know where to start, please can you help me out. I just want to preventDefault it and without pageload sending the e-mail.

This is the Javascript ( i think only the id is needed I wont post the whole code )

```
form id = #contact-form
```

The HTML

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="contact" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 style="color:#31708f" class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Contact</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form role="form" name"contact-form" id="contact-form" method="post" action="contactengine.php">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="name" />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="e-mail">E-mail adres</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" name="email" />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="subject" type="text" name="subject" />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="bericht">Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea> 
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-info" id="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: Well.. you have to show more code. Let us see what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not JavaScript: `form id = #contact-form`.

Basically what you want to do is first making it work without AJAX and JavaScript. You need to have the PHP stuff working on the server.

Then, you use some JavaScript to prevent the Form from being sent (this is with jQuery):

```
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Here you send the ajax-request to the php-script.
    $.ajax('send.php', {
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data); //for testing
        }
    });
});
```

See for example the [jQuery documentation about ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for further information about how to send the request.

Comment: Lars, Thank you very much. I already had it working on PHP with phpmailer. So it didn't took long. I realy didn't know where to start with AJAX. But this helped me out, only need to give the success message, but that is the easy work. Thank you!

Comment: @Daan: Thanks for clarification, I made that point not very clear in my answer. But especially Ajax is a pain in the behind if you do it without any framework. Plus, I did not know how to do it without jQuery from the top of my head.